# How does the choice of vegetable ratio and processing steps influence the taste of mirepoix?

Tags: sauce, flavor, sauteing

There are sources on the internet, but each one touches only one or two areas and some contradict each other. For example they say "two parts onions for other veggies" but videos always show equal parts onion to carrot and celery ratio.

I believe that simply explaining the process behind making a flavor base (how the veggies interact with each other, the role of fat, how dicing size affects the end result etc) will help us all make better informed decisions for our own preferences in whatever flavor base we choose to make.

Comment: Hi Bar Akiva, I'm afraid your question is unanswerable. Your second paragraph is basically a definition of "recipe". And the first one illustrates nicely why we don't take recipe requests: because there are tons of them and it is impossible to say that one is better than the other. "Perfect" is the one which tastes best to you personally, and that's, well, a matter of taste.

Comment: Hello rumtscho. Thank you for the helpful comment. I will edit my question and see if I can make it more concise.

Comment: Thank you for your edit! The edit bumped the question up, so I saw it was changed. "How do I upgrade the flavor base" is still not answerable (it depends on what you're doing already, what you prefer tastewise, etc.) but the rest of it will hopefully get good answers, so I edited it again, keeping the spirit of your newer version. Also, a technical matter: you get notifications for all comments posted on your question or answer. Other people only get notified if you place an @ sign before their handle in the comment. If you want somebody to note something you said, using @ makes it easier.

Comment: I think whatever becomes of that question would be helped by defining "two parts, one part..." by weight or volume ... this is only one part (by weight) irony to three parts trying to make the best of it - this question is about tuning stuff with some precision...

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party but ....

Onion and celery have similar effect in the mirepoix, the leeks will have a similar effect but with more depth on the sweet side & carrot will bring some sweetness.

Based on that, depending on what you want to cook, there are some guidelines.

1. For stews, keep in mind that some of the next ingredients might add some sweetness to the meal, so it's ok to equal the onion and celery parts to the other veggies.
2. For broth you might want to reduce the onion and celery part to 1/2 part of other vegetables (carrot, mushrooms, tomato paste, etc.) knowing it will eventually reduce into a demi-glace and that you will season it with spices and aromates. Reducing mean the flavor will concentrate.
3. For soup / potage you should adjust to the main ingredient to balance it out, usually I go with onion and celery in equal part and no carrots unless you want the soup / potage to have a sweet taste, which is ok for pea soup, tomato, carrot, etc.

Hope it helps,